# How to set background image for entire screen in app js file in react js?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Hi i am new to react and i need to Create a login page with background image, i created a new login component and i called i the app.js, now if i write any css property it wil affect only the login component but i need background image as full cover.

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqPqa.jpg)

[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqKZN.png)

My app.js code is:

```
var sectionStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "400px",
  backgroundImage: "url(" + ( Background ) + ")"
};

class Section extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section style={ sectionStyle }>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
                return (
            <div className="App">
                <Login />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My login.js code is:

```
render() {

        const { errors, formSubmitted } = this.state;

        return (

            <div className="Login"  style={divStyle}>
                <Row>
                    <form onSubmit={this.login}>
                        <FormGroup controlId="email" validationState={ formSubmitted ? (errors.email ? 'error' : 'success') : null }>
                            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        { errors.email &&
                            <HelpBlock>{errors.email}</HelpBlock>
                        }
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup controlId="password" validationState={ formSubmitted ? (errors.password ? 'error' : 'success') : null }>
                            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        { errors.password &&
                            <HelpBlock>{errors.password}</HelpBlock>
                        }
                        </FormGroup>
                        <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">Sign-In</Button>
                    </form>
                </Row>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: `import img from "../../assets/img/logo(name).svg";                 
                                                                                                                           
    render() { <img id="logo-img"  src={img} alt="logo" /> }  `                                                                                                                                              Hope this will help you

Comment: @oshini in app.js?

Comment: I was tried in login.jsx. But the same way should work . but need to apply your own css styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to get your expected output . It works for me . under content of the page.

```
import img from "../../assets/img/logo(name).svg";

   render() {
        return (
            <div className="content" style={{ overflow: "auto"}}>
                 <img id="logo-img" src={img} alt="logo" /> 
            </div>
       )
    }
```

Comment: working fine thanks and i added another question too kindly look over there.

Comment: please share the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188535/how-to-replace-image-as-icon-in-a-const-in-react-js